# Function to reverse order of linked list... last node does not link to rest of list

Tags: c

I have the following node structure in C:

```
#define SIZE 5 

typedef struct node
{
    int n;
    struct node* next;
}node;

node* head = NULL; 

void implement(int n); // create linked list 
int length(void); // returns length of list 
node* reverse(void); // reverses order of list
```

The list is implemented as follows:

```
void implement (int n)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if(new_node == NULL)
        {
            printf("out of memory!\n");
            return;
        }

        new_node->n = i; 
        new_node->next = head;
        head = new_node;  

    }
}
```

Which when printed to the terminal gives:

4 3 2 1 0

The head pointer is set to node 4.

I have written the following function to reverse the list as follows:

```
node* reverse(void)
{  

    node* cur = head;
    node* next = NULL; 
    head = NULL;

    while (cur->next != NULL)
    {
        next = cur->next; 
        cur->next = head;   
        head = cur; 
        cur = next;    
    }   



    return cur; 
}
```

However, returning cur only gives:

0

Returning head provides:

1 2 3 4

So it is quite clear that the list is being reversed, but for some reason the last node (0) is not being linked to the remaining nodes. I am probably missing something obvious here, but can anyone give me any pointers? (no pun intended!)

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (cur->next != NULL)
```

This stops when `cur` is at the last element (`next` is `NULL`); i.e. you don't process the last node.

Changing it to

```
while (cur != NULL)
```

and returning `head` should fix it.

Comment: Cheers, that did the job! Probably should have left this one till morning lol.

Comment: @Matthew2015 Whenever designing an algorithm for a linked list, consider at least four special cases: lists with zero to three items. An empty list (zero items) is an obvious special case, three is the smallest 'quite normal' case for most of algorithms (it has a head node, a tail  node and at least one node which has both a 'prev' and a 'next' node).

Comment: Thanks@CiaPan. I'll bare this in mind in the future... I will be looking at that bubble sort of linked lists with strings soon so I'll let you know how it goes!